# Loading multiple files with require statement on JS

Tags: javascript, protractor, requirejs, cucumber, pageobjects

The execution returns the following error when trying to load multiple js:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined
```

The solution that I am implementing has a **login_steps.js**:

```
var LoginSteps = function() {

var LoginSteps = require("../pages/pages.js");
browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;

this.World = function MyWorld() {
    this.page = new LoginSteps();
};

this.Given(/^the page is open$/, function (callback) {
    this.page.login_page.get();
    callback();
});
};

module.exports = LoginSteps;
```

A **page.js** where I want to include all the modules that I need.

```
var Pages = function() {
module.exports = {
    shipments_page: require('./shipments_page.js'),
    login_page: require('./login_page.js'),
};
};

module.exports = Pages;
```

And the modules **login_page.js:**

```
var chai = require('chai').use(require('chai-as-promised'));
var expect = chai.expect;

this.get = function() {
    browser.get('https://aaa/login');
};

this.setEmail = function(value) {
    element(by.id('login-email')).sendKeys(value);
};

this.setPassword = function(value) {
    element(by.id('login-password')).sendKeys(value);
};

this.clickAccede = function() {
    element(by.id('login-submit')).click()
};
```

**shipment_page.js:**

```
var chai = require('chai').use(require('chai-as-promised'));
var expect = chai.expect;

this.pageIsLoaded = function() {
    browser.waitForAngular();
    expect(browser.getTitle()).to.be.eventually.equals('title');
};
```

Then when I execute the test the log shows

```
Failures:

1) Scenario: User login - features/login.feature:3
Step: Given the page is open - features/login.feature:4
Step Definition: features/steps/login_steps.js:16
Message:
 TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined
     at MyWorld.<anonymous> (/Users/mj/IdeaProjects/atpro/features/steps/login_steps.js:17:30)
     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:61:11)

1 scenario (1 failed)
5 steps (1 failed, 4 skipped)
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: @Jer, I want to be able to call functions from differents js files from login_steps.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code that you can try. Its works for me. I modified based on your code snippet. I won't use this pattern in my tests though.You may not want to write protractor-cucumber test using the pattern you are following. One should always use validation/assertions in step definition code. if you do validation in page object, even your validation fails, your test still will show passed.

login_steps.js

```
var LoginSteps = function() {

var LoginSteps = require("../pages/pages.js");
browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;

this.World = function MyWorld() {
this.page = LoginSteps;
};

this.Given(/^the page is open$/, function (callback) {
this.page.login_page.get();
callback();
});
};

module.exports = LoginSteps;
```

pages.js:

```
 module.exports = {
 shipments_page: require('./shipments_page.js'),
 login_page: require('./login_page.js'),
 };
```

Comment: I think I am missing something: 
   Message:
     TypeError: this.page.login_page.get is not a function
         at MyWorld.<anonymous> (/Users/marianojover/IdeaProjects/aaa/features/steps/login_steps.js:11:30)
         at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:61:11)

Comment: did you use this.page.login_page.get  or this.page.login_page.get()?

Comment: it worked! I was using this.page.login_page.get() but the problem was in login_page.js

Answer (score 0):

If I interpreted correctly this is what you want. You have only to change page.js a little.

```
module.exports = function() {
   this.shipments_page = require('./shipments_page.js');
   this.login_page = require('./login_page.js');
};
```

Please try this. I cannot test at the moment :=)